# Weird Vuejs props behavior with arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a form component where i pass an object prop to it containing strings and an object array. I then i transfer the elements of the props to the component variables so i can edit them without interacting with the props directly like so:

```
beforeMount(){
    this.var1 = this.props.var1
    this.var2 = this.props.var2
    this.array = this.props.array
}
```

when i edit all the other variables, close my component and open it again everything resets BESIDES the array. every time i try to interact with it the reset never happens. i know i am not interreacting directly with the props either in any part of my code so i don't really why this happens when when everything works fine. To fix that i had to do the following:

```
beforeMount(){
        this.var1 = this.props.var1
        this.var2 = this.props.var2
        this.props.array.forEach(element => {
           this.array.push(element)
        })
    }
```

why does this work exactly?
I have also been having similar problems with method specific variables not resetting after the function is already over so i find these behaviors a little weird. I am also using "v-if" and also tried to use component keys to  reset the component but it doesn't work for the array for whatever reason.

Comment: You can also make use of the lifecycle method `beforeDestroy` and empty out all the variables/arrays you want. Did you try that one already?

Comment: not yet. i'll try it now.

Comment: i just did it and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to copy your array like that :

```
    this.array = [...this.props.array]
```

I'm not sure about it, but as you pass it within an object, you might actually use you array as reference and not values as you 'd like to.

Comment: Perfect. I think that passing an object with all props you want to pass to children"s component is not recommended by Vuejs.
[From vuejs doc :](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object) : **Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.**

Comment: oh which is why i am copying its content to the components variables so i dont mess with  the props by any means. which is why it was so weird because th props would stay the same while the component variable wouldn't update. ill study about it later today.